# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am getting error message:

> Invalid argument for foreach() in my View.

I want to display but getting error Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`. I am a newbie in Codeigniter and couldn't really figure out how to solve this.

**Model**

```
function get_berita($WHERE=array())
{
    $this->db->select('id_berita,judul_berita,content,tanggal');
    $this->db->where($WHERE);
    $this->db->order_by('id_berita','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get('berita_ukm');
    return $query -> result_array();
}
```

**Controller**

```
function index()
{
    $this->data['berita'] = $this->mberita->get_berita();
    $this->data['title'] ='UKM Taekwondo | berita';
    $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
    $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('admin/berita/view_berita', '', true);          
    $this->load->view('template/wrapper/admin/wrapper_ukm',$this->data);
}
```

**View**

```
<tbody>
<?php
$no=1;
foreach ($berita as $dt) {
   echo "
    <tr>
    <td>$dt[id_berita]</td>
    <td>$dt[tanggal]</td>
        <td>$dt[judul_berita]</td>
    <td>$dt[content]</td>
    <td><a class='ui tiny blue edit button' href='".base_url()."index.php/admin/berita/edit/$dt[id_berita]'><i class='edit icon'></i></a>
    <a class='ui tiny blue edit button' href='".base_url()."index.php/admin/berita/delete/$dt[id_berita]'><i class='trash icon'></i></a></td>
    </tr>
   ";
   $no++;
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Please help me what to do. Thank you.

Comment: Please show what `var_dump($this->mberita->get_berita());` is giving you.

Comment: i try this but result array(0) { }. can you tell me why array(0)? thank you

Comment: This means it is an empty array. And that is why you receive this error. A foreach requires an array with at least one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your model returning an empty set thats but foreach needs an array to work .. 
you can ignore this error by embed an if condition before foreach ...

```
    if($berita){
      foreach ($berita as $dt) {
        echo "<tr>
                  <td>$dt[id_berita]</td>
                  <td>$dt[tanggal]</td>
                  <td>$dt[judul_berita]</td>
                  <td>$dt[content]</td>
                  <td><a class='ui tiny blue edit button' href='".base_url()."index.php/admin/berita/edit/$dt[id_berita]'><i class='edit icon'></i></a>
                  <a class='ui tiny blue edit button' href='".base_url()."index.php/admin/berita/delete/$dt[id_berita]'><i class='trash icon'></i></a></td>

              </tr>";
          $no++;
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you but still error Undefined variable: berita. how solve this error? thank you

Comment: on your controller modify this line $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('admin/berita/view_berita', $this->data, true);

Answer (score 0):

Your model return no values.
do a check before posting the data to your controller
in your ***model***

```
 function get_berita($WHERE=array())
 {

  $query = $this->db->select('id_berita,judul_berita,content,tanggal')
                    ->from('berita_ukm')
                    ->where($WHERE)
                    ->order_by('id_berita','asc')
                    ->get();

  $query->num_rows() > 0 ? return $query->result_array() : array();

 }
```

Comment: i try var_dump get_berita but array(0){}. what to do?

Comment: do you have any data in your database? also in your controller you have passed an empty parameter to 'get_berita($WHERE)' model  $this->data['berita'] = $this->mberita->get_berita(????);